# Check if multiple elements exist in one if statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using waypoints.js and it breaks when I am not on the page that it is targeting.

To fix this I have to check if the element exists on the page before running the waypoints function like this:

```
if (jQuery(".section-2-box").length) {
   //my code             
}

if (jQuery(".section-3-box").length) {
   //my code             
}

if (jQuery(".section-4-box").length) {
   //my code             
}
```

It works, but the problem is that I have so many elements I need to check. I don't want to have to write out 20 if statements.

Is it possible to just do one if statement to do some type of logic like "if all of these elements exist then run some code"?

Comment: Give the elements multiple classes? ie. <input class="section section-4-box" /> then do $('.section').length

Comment: that is one solution thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Can you change the html?  Add a single class to your body/top-level div on the page you want to enable the code and check for that one class.

Comment: Yup I was just thinking that, that is most likely the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you **know** there is only one element with each of those classes, then a standard group selector can do it:

```
if (jQuery(".section-2-box, .section-3-box, .section-4-box").length === 3)
```

If not (there might be two `section-2-box`s and no `section-3-box`), you probably have to throw jQuery-specific `:first`s in there:

```
if (jQuery(".section-2-box:first, .section-3-box:first, .section-4-box:first").length === 3)
```

Example:

```js
if (jQuery(".section-2-box:first, .section-3-box:first, .section-4-box:first").length === 3) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}
```

```html
<div>We should see "no" because there is no .section-3-box</div>
<div class="section-2-box"></div>
<div class="section-2-box"></div>
<div class="section-4-box"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this will work but this method I need to write out every instance of the class right?

Comment: @cup_of: Yes. If you can give us a clearer idea what you're doing (will there only ever be one of each, for instance), we can be more precise helping you. For instance, if there's only ever one of each, add a common class to them and check for that. But if you could have two `section-2-box` and no `section-3-box`, the common class won't help much; you'll need a loop checking for distinct `section-x-box` class names.

Comment: so I have a bunch of waypoint functions on my homepage, and when im not on the homepage I get errors in the console because my main.js is connected to all pages and it is looking for those elements. since im not on the homepage those elements dont exist so i get an error. I think i can fix this by setting a homepage flag and doing an if statement saying if that flag exists then run all my waypoints in that if statement